# how to fetch data in api in react js based id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to fetch data in api in react js based id.i make one table in my below code i want to make when i click on row first then fetch data its based on 1st click row.https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54.  this is my api i try to make but iam unable to do that.i want when i click on row1 then fetch data which id is 2 in api how can we do that

```
class TableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  handleRowClick = async () => {
    // make an API call here, sth like
    const url = "https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    this.setState({
      ...response,
    });
  };

  render() {
    var dataColumns = this.props.data.columns;
    var dataRows = this.props.data.rows;

    var tableHeaders = (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {" "}
          {dataColumns.map(function (column) {
            return <th> {column} </th>;
          })}{" "}
        </tr>{" "}
      </thead>
    );

    var tableBody = dataRows.map((row) => {
      return (
        <tr onClick={this.handleRowClick}>
          {" "}
          {dataColumns.map(function (column) {
            return (
              <td>
                {" "}
                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={row.url}>
                  {" "}
                  {row[column]}{" "}
                </a>
              </td>
            );
          })}{" "}
        </tr>
      );
    });

    // Decorate with Bootstrap CSS
    return (
      <table className="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        {" "}
        {tableHeaders} {tableBody}{" "}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

// Example Data
var tableData = {
 columns: ['Service_Name', 'Cost/Unit'],
  rows: [{
    'Service_Name': 'airplane',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
   
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'cat',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  },{
    'Service_Name': 'fruits',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'pool',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  }]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent data = {tableData} />,
  document.getElementById('table-component'));
```

Comment: anybody help me out

Comment: Can you please explain your doubt clearly in your description, m unable to understand your ask here, thank you

Comment: is it something like, you want to fetch a single element from that API based on some parameter? If yes, then you need to have some logic in backend API to return matching elements based on your params, if it's single you route like `some.domain/route/<id to be fetched>` but you need to have same unique element on frontend to pass it to backend because currently from your data I dnt see you have any common IDs.

Comment: first of all thanks for reply

Comment: yes right this type something i want actually i m new n this can u help m out

Comment: i want to make n my code here https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM i make one table and when i click on table first row then fetch id 1 and when i click 4th row then fetch id 4 how can we do that

Comment: https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM cn u help me out n here

Comment: basically i want to make when i click on first row airplane then fetch the data id 1 open the url and next when i click on row4th then fectch id 4 in  api and open url like that i want to make

Comment: hope u getting my point

Comment: this can not be accomplished unless your mock API is configured to return data based on `id` passed like following URL: `https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54/<:id>`
and that ID need to be there in mock response

Comment: https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54/<:id> ok thanks

Comment: can u help me out https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM this and show me

Comment: can u show me something in some editor its very thankful bcz i m stuck on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add unique ID in your `tableData` for every row data. now that ID will be used while creating table as `key` for every row as React's guidelines and also passed to `handleRowClick` function based on the row user is click

https://codepen.io/rohit-ambre/pen/NWdJpbp

check above codepen, I have made small changes in handleClick function. (currently it returns all the data)

But to complete your expectations here, your mock API is dumb as in it has no logic to return based on any parameter passed to it. I'm not sure about mocki.io if it is possible or no. Otherwise, you can create a simple express app in local to return based on ID passed. then your URL will changed as following

`https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54/:id` and API should only return data associated with that id.

EDIT: I have modified my codepen to use other API which has logic.
Also if you're getting CORS error then for time being install [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en).

I have created small glitch project which has 2 APIs to return data based on params-wise API or Query wise, I have commented both URLs in my codepen.

API info:

1. `https://grandiose-mulberry-garnet.glitch.me/query?id=<id>` this API uses query parameters to accept id, if you don't pass id like `https://grandiose-mulberry-garnet.glitch.me/query` then it'll return all records
2. `https://grandiose-mulberry-garnet.glitch.me/params/<id>` this API is uses route params to accept id, it is mandatory to pass id here.

FYI: In both APIs you need to replace `<id>` with any value like 1,2,4,3, etc

Comment: what u can shared in code pen but i m not able to click.can u plz check and help me out .

Comment: and i create simply fake api

Comment: u can use diff.its also fine

Comment: simply i want to make when i click on 1st row 2nd row .... then open url which is fetched in api

Comment: Check console if your getting CORS error, if yes then for time being use chrome CORS plugin and try

Comment: just now i check chrome not able to do plz help me out

Comment: check my codepen now and use extension chrome extension for CORS issue to test it (link given in description).

Comment: https://codepen.io/svpan/pen/NWdJvmX?editors=1010  trying to using same but when i click on row first then url is not open ??

Comment: any idea on that ??

Comment: check browser console, u must be getting CORS error, please install CORS extension to test.

Comment: the main question has been resolved if you look at the react code from codepen and try to implement your code accordingly. Upvote the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: yes in console i m getting id but i want in my code clickable row when i click airplane 1st row then open url which id is 1 in fetched api

Comment: how can we do that

Comment: can u help me out??

Comment: It is working as expected, it does open image in new tab only problem is CORS issue, I cant help to install that, I have already said 100 times i guess, did you try it by using activation CORS extension after installing it?

Comment: yes i already install and activate cors  but i dont know why not happen

Comment: yes, it is working perfectly in my browser.

Comment: ist possible can u shared m snaps

Comment: i m literrally stuck on that

Comment: try this [video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EovEJHBnLyvf7-5xipfPMfcAJ_KKudim/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I might delete that link tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for ur help and support thanku so much

Comment: And one thing what is api which u call can u give me url link

Comment: Bcz I open api url link I m not able to see any data

Comment: I have edited the Answer with some description about backend APIs in the last pls go through that.

Comment: thanks for help and support .its very thankful.

Comment: Make sure you read on things you're implementing to learn better. Good luck